# When to chose jersey binding vs. bias binding

Tags: sewing, fabric

I recently had a problem with binding a rectangle of fabric with rounded corners. The fabric had a slight stretch to it and the corner was rounded off about an inch / 3 cm, so no sharp angle there.

Initially I bought jersey binding, because it looked best on my fabric. It looks exactly like bias binding (is prefolded the same way), but instead of a (non-stretch) plain weave cut on the bias, it's cut straight from (stretchy) jersey. Here's a random example:

[image]

The problem was that - even after intense ironing - **I couldn't get the corner to lay flat**. The jersey always seemed to pull on the corners, curling them in.

So I ripped the binding off again and repeated the process with plain cotton bias binding. This time I had no problem at all ironing the corners flat.

My question is: **When should I chose jersey vs. bias binding for my sewing project?** Is the use of jersey binding limited to certain areas of applications (like inward curves vs. outward curves)?